# Registry security settings

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I’m trying to access a certain bit of the registry however it keeps returning null when i try to open it.

However i know the location is correct because i can navigate to it in reedit.

here’s my line of code for trying to access it.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey RK = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubK("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UserData", false);
```

any one got any ideas?

**update**

it looks like i am seeing a different version fo the registery, this need to be a 32bit app but it needs to be able to see the 32bit and 64bit version of the registery.

Thank you

Comment: It may happen that you see different versions of the registry depending on if you run x86 or x64 code, and I think also on your privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you apply permissions to access the registry key via the attribute `[System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.RegistryPermission)]` or are you running the program as administrator? Here's a detailed look at the Security Permissions as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.aspx), more aptly [RegistryPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.registrypermission.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var tempKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
```

and for Security access

```
var rule = new RegistryAccessRule(LOGON_USER_NAME, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);
var security = new RegistrySecurity();
security.AddAccessRule(rule);
tempKey.SetAccessControl(security);

 tempKey = tempkey.OpenSubKey(SUB_KEY, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

and for LOGON_USER_NAME

1)

```
var LOGON_USER_NAME = Environment.UserName;
```

2)

```
var LOGON_USER_NAME = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your application being run? In other words, what context does your application run under? Is it being run by double clicking on the .exe or is a setup application firing up the process? Setup applications run under a different context than you would expect.

Comment: its running as a windows sevice